# Can I call C#, or C++, from html pages for server-side scripting/programming on localhost?

Tags: c#, php, .net, asp.net

I am running Aprelium Abyss Web Server from my home computer and I have a plain old normal website.

You know how you can have separate PHP files, and then call the functions inside of then within the HTML page using the onclick="" of a button?

Well, I have a C# and C++ program on my computer (where the server is located), and would like to know if I can somehow send a command from my html page to my C# or C++ program which will then execute a function, and return a result.

Here's a scenario:

User visits http://samplesite.com/blah.html

User clicks the 'Create some files' button on the webpage

Webpage sends command to C# application on my computer/webserver

C# application creates a bunch of empty files

C# application sends back filenames of the generated files to the webpage

the webpage then displays a list of the filenames that were generated byb the C# application.

Can somebody please guide me in the right direction?

In this case, Security will not be an issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how that C# application exposes it's members.

If the other C# application is a DLL, you reference the DLL in your ASP.NET project and call it's methods.

If it is a web service you can also make a reference to it as a web reference and then call it's methods.

Regardless, your ASP.NET web site must somehow make a reference to the other C# application to be able to communicate with it.